# Is my junction table in this ERD correct?

Tags: database-design, erd

The table on the right[SampleID] has as PK the 'Sample_id', which is a concatenation of all values above.

However, [SampleDepth] and [SampleType] are together in a 'many-to-many' relationship, therefore a junction table was inserted (in blue).

Did I connect the right relationships for this junction table?

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) DDL is ERD text. Please put all but only what is needed to ask/answer in a post.

Comment: Where & how/why are you 1st stuck following what published presentation of what design method? It's not clear what your reasoning is when you say "therefore a junction table was inserted" given "are together in a 'many-to-many' relationship". Moreover the 2 statements more or less say the same thing, a table represents an association/relation(ship) on values/entities, you don't explain the business rules to justify the statements. (Presumably you think the latter is the business rule but then why are you in doubt?)